# pass windows 10 touchpad gestures to remote desktop

Tags: windows, gesture, remote-desktop

I was just wondering if it's possible (even with a third party software) to pass the touchpad gestures from a laptop running windows 10 to a pc (no touchpad available) using RD.
I`m interested especially in passing the swipe with four fingers gestures( the one that switches between desktops)

Thanks

Comment: Also wanting this

Answer (score 0):

try installing synaptics drivers(even if there is no touchpad) on the Remote Machine

btw

you can always use shortcut keys

check virtual desktop section on

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)